# Unable to erase, reformat, or repartition USB drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility

This afternoon I attempted to mount a .iso of Windows 7 to a bootable USB drive. It's about 370GiB, so more than enough to store it. I did the following to get myself into this mess. Note,`/sda/disk2` is the right disk.

```
mightybee at mightybook.T-mobile.com in [~]   
12:06:27 › sudo dd if=/Users/mightybee/Desktop/en_windows_10_multiple_editions_version_1511_x64_dvd_7223712.iso of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m
12:10:21 › diskutil eject /dev/disk2
```

After that, I was left with a disk that was reformatted to look like this:
[image: diskutil]

The disk is not bootable and doesn't do what I wanted it to do. Furthermore, the disk is actually un-reformattable, unreadable, and practically unusable. When I run eraseDisk, I get this:

```
diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 WINSEVEN /dev/disk2 
Unable to begin erase operation: The target disk is too small for this operation (-69771)
```

So my question is this: How do I regain the ability to erase and try another method to write to this disk?

Comment: What happens when you click the erase control in the screen capture above? What is the exact command for "eraseDisk" - I'm presuming it's diskutil.

Comment: Sorry about the cutoff: you're right, the full command for eraseDisk is diskutil. I was using DiskUtility.app just to display some info about the disk. Clicking erase (and using any format) returns an error with 'Name Invalid'. I tried using the FAT32 naming convention of all caps and it still returned that message.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your command should work if your disk looks something like mine below (note disk1 vs disk2):

```
diskutil list disk1
/dev/disk1 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +1.5 GB     disk1
   1:       Microsoft Basic Data WINSEVEN                1.5 GB     disk1s1
```

I would unmount the disk as opposed to ejecting it next time.

```
diskutil unmountDisk disk2
```

You can pull the drive and reconnect it and see if a lower level erase is possible.

```
diskutil eraseVolume FAT32 WIN8 /dev/disk2s1
```

I would expect you to use FAT32 with `eraseVolume` as opposed to `eraseDisk` so you might need to repartition things first and then try erasing the volume or recreating it.

```
diskutil partitionDisk disk2 1 MBR FAT32 WINSEVEN R
```

After the above command - you should have something similar to the below with the exception of disk2 replacing disk1

```
$ diskutil partitionDisk disk1 1 MBR FAT32 WINSEVEN R
Started partitioning on disk1
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Waiting for the disks to reappear
Formatting disk1s1 as MS-DOS (FAT32) with name WINSEVEN
512 bytes per physical sector
/dev/rdisk1s1: 2923976 sectors in 365497 FAT32 clusters (4096 bytes/cluster)
bps=512 spc=8 res=32 nft=2 mid=0xf8 spt=32 hds=255 hid=2 drv=0x80 bsec=2929726 bspf=2856 rdcl=2 infs=1 bkbs=6
Mounting disk
Finished partitioning on disk1
/dev/disk1 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        +1.5 GB     disk1
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 WINSEVEN                1.5 GB     disk1s1
```

Comment: Thanks. In case anyone comes searching, if you see "Error creating partition map: The target disk is too small for this operation (-69771)", then you should do `diskutil unmountDisk disk3` first and then it works. Stupid error message.