# Operation failed when I tried to create a partition

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, startup, partition

I'm trying to create a partition in following "Part 2: Preparing your Mac" from this [website](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs171/materials/pdfs/How_to_Dual-Boot_OSX_and_Ubuntu.pdf). I have to create "Ubuntu Boot Loader" in selecting the principal hard drive "APPLE SSD AP0512J Media", select `Partition` -> `+` -> `Name : Ubuntu Boot Loader` -> `Format : Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` -> `Size: 128 MB`, but I got the following error with Disk Utility :

[image]

[image]

I got the following message when I hit "Show Details" :

> Running operation 1 of 1…
>   Checking prerequisites for resizing Logical-Physical volume stack
>   The requested size change for the target disk or a related disk is too small. Please try a different disk or partition, or make a larger change.
>   Operation failed…

[image]

Could anyone be able to tell what do I have to do to fix the "Operation failed"?

Comment: Glad things are sorted out. Dug this answer up just now - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/240326/unable-to-erase-reformat-or-repartition-usb-drive

Comment: Tip: you might not be creating a real gpt partition but a logical partition using corestorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like it says in the error box, **try making a bigger partition**. The partition you are trying to create is only 128 mb. Even though it says create a 128MB partition(in the guide), it wouldn't cause any problems to increase the size of the partition since there are errors for creating a partition of the size 128MB.

Comment: Did you see the website? I have to create two partition : one of 128MB and another with at least 50GB

Comment: @SandraRoss Updated my answer